# What Babelify presets/plugins am I missing to parse this code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, browserify, babelify

I'm using a Rails 4.0 project that implements [Browserify-Rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to implement [Babelify](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets).

Everything seems to be going hunky dory on my local, and remote Beta server. But when I deploy to production, certain files will be skipped if they have in them, a `require("")` .

My original settings were this :

```
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = ["-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react stage-0 ] --plugins [ syntax-async-functions transform-regenerator ] ]"]
```

Which made it skip over a file that had this line in it :

```
var { configureStore } = require('./configureStore');
```

That require lead here :

```
let { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } = require('redux');
let thunk = require('redux-thunk').default
let session = require('./reducers/session').default;
let search = require('./reducers/search').default;

const configureStore = () => {
  const reducers = combineReducers({
    session,
    search,
  });

  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  return createStore(
    reducers,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
}

export { configureStore };
```

I was guessing maybe there's a couple JS stylings I'm using here that are above ES2015

So I went ahead and played with the configs, adding Incremental, and updating to ES2017. Which got me past that broken file. My new config looked like this :

```
config.browserify_rails.use_browserifyinc = true
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = ["-t [ babelify --presets [ es2017 react stage-0 ] --plugins [ syntax-async-functions transform-regenerator ] ]", "-t coffeeify --extension=\".js.coffee\""]
```

But this gets me as far as this line in a further file :

```
let { search } = require('../../actions/search');
```

Which loads this ( and mind you, the follow file was parsed and translated just fine ) :

```
export const SEARCH_RESULTS_RECEIVED = 'SEARCH_RESULTS_RECEIVED';

export const search = (term, token) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    if (term && term.trim() !== '') {
      return _search(term, token).then((results) => dispatch(resultsReceived(results)));
    } else {
      return dispatch(resultsReceived([]));
    }
  }
};

const _search = (term, token) => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(encodeURI(`/api/search?search=${term}`), {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Token ${token}`
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      return resolve(response.results);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return reject(error);
    });
  });

  return promise;
};

export const resultsReceived = (searchResults) => ({
  type: SEARCH_RESULTS_RECEIVED,
  searchResults
});
```

I'm curious if there's any Babelify plugins/presets that I might be missing in order to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yearly presets only contain the features that were added that year - i.e. `es2017` doesn't include any of the stuff from the `es2015` and `es2016` presets!

This set of presets ought to solve your problem:

```
es2015 es2016 es2017 react stage-0
```

That said, the preferred way to include all the latest yearly presets is to use the [`env` preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/), which pulls in all of them, will update once ES2018 is released, and also allows you to configure things based on your target environment if you want:

```
env react stage-0
```

Comment: Yo!!! Thank you so much Joe! I honestly couldn't find this answer anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @Trip: Glad I could help, I think a lot of people get confused by this! For future reference, all the official presets are documented [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/).